# Ubuntu 16.04 progress dots remain flashing in centre of screen after successful boot

Tags: boot

Ubuntu 16.04. Boots successfully with Ubuntu logo with five progress dots under logo changing from white to red. Ubuntu logo disappears, boot is successful but the five progress dots remain, flashing in sequence. I have turned the grid off in Tweak to no avail.
No new programs installed, all updates installed. Only started doing this two or three days ago.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I removed `nomodeset` from after `quiet splash`, and it seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 (yesterday)
Today I found that just silencing the audio on Rhythmbox was all it took to prevent the five blinking dots from showing up on the desktop after a [Restart]. Even if I didn't close the program before doing the [Restart] or [Shutdown]. I tried all. If I closed the program with the audio still playing, I still got the five blinking dots. So, I had to silence it first. If you forget. Just re-open Rhythmbox, silence it and then close it and do the [Restart].