# Ubuntu 18.04 - qemu VM: Loading bar from start-screen still on desktop

Tags: 18.04, qemu

I start up my VM of the newest 18.04 LTS-Version. From time to time the start-screen does not disappear like usual.

The image shown below overlaps all other windows, every time it updates (a point changes the color). It mostly disappears on the next reboot.

How can I get rid of it and is this a bug worth reporting?

**EDIT:** On startup, the dots are not displayed correct. They are spread pixel-line by pixel-line over the top edge of the boot screen.

[image: This Desktop]

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025946/ubuntu-16-04-progress-dots-remain-flashing-in-centre-of-screen-after-successful and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123882/plymouth-loading-dots-on-desktop

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this problem while using ubuntu 19.10 x86_64 in a qemu session controlled by `virt-manager` using the spice display.  I resolved it by editing `/etc/default/grub` using the command:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

(if your not a vim junkie, substitute nano for vim in the above command). Once the file is open remove "quiet splash" from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, probably leaving an empty string.  To apply the update type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Enjoy!

Comment: ok. nice one! but it's a work arround (a goood one ;). You have described my setup in detail, so "same"! does somebody now how to investigate in this? Would it be an idea to file a bugreport against ubuntu? looks like it happens not only to me. This looks like a bug, cause this splash gif is not killed. hmmmm....

Comment: I didn't have time to investigate where the issue was but I suspect it is something to do with how the spice protocol or virt-manager viewer handles the ubuntu loading screen graphic.